# Google apps script - send a single email per row by clicking a link or using the popup window?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out which trigger to use to send an email (from a template) per row:

```
  function sendConfirmationEmail(e) {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
// Test
  
  console.log('Data: ' + e + 'range ' + dataRange);

}
```

**A/** I am trying to add a column F with sendEmail and somehow trigger the function sendConfirmationEmail(e) in the script

[image: sendEmail]

**B/** Trying to figure out if I can use the onhover email (column E) and when clicking Send email my emailTemplate.doc will be populated and replace the {{placeholder}} default message.
[image][image]

Any tips, suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the function on writing the string `sendEmail` into a cell in column F?

Comment: @ziganotschka, well in an ideal situation I would like it to be a button. So by onClick I would like to read the corresponding row values and send Email.

I am going to try out your suggestion/answer!

Comment: On a button would also be possible, but then you either need to make a separate button for each row or make sure you click into the right row before clicking on the button - onEdit trigger is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To trigger a function on editing a cell content - use the [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

- This trigger contains the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) `e.range` that allows you to access the cell that has been edited.
- Given that sending an email is an action that requires authorization, you need to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of simple `onEdit` trigger
- This you can do by calling your function something different from the key word `onEdit` (this is already the case in your function) and bind a trigger to it as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Sample function to bind on installable onEdit trigger:

```js
  function sendConfirmationEmail(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  // for column F
  if(column ==6 && e.value == "sendEmail"){
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).getValues().flat();
    var email = dataRange[4];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "subject", "body");
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 general questions, how can I make replaceText to work:
` var message = 'Congratulations {{YourName}}';
    message.replaceText("{{YourName}}", "Elon");
    // GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "subject", message);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Text " + message); `


2/ I am trying to use console.log("Body " + message); but I am not sure how to use the console log as I don't see anything in the Chrome browser log

I have a seperate email bodytext which I like to use

Comment: oh I tried 3 different approaches to use a template file in the email body only the last seems to work:
  // .1
    //  var bodyText = sheet.getRange("J10").getValues();
    // .2
    //  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("confirmMsgTmpl").getContent();
    // htmlBody.replace("{{YourName}}", fName);
    // .3
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('confirmMsgTmpl');
    htmlTemplate.name = fName;
    var emailBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate();
    htmlBody = emailBody.getContent();

Comment: To your first question: I believe you already found a solution? To the second: Apps Script server-side logs you will find under executions - see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging.